# Syntax error when creating procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a procedure, but I am always getting syntax error and it is marking me "(" or ",". Iam using version 6.3. Can somebody help me to fix this problem? And here is my code[image]

Comment: I think you are confusing `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement syntax. Also please read why you [should not post screenshots of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: In addition to comment above, why are you creating a procedure that only does an insert?

Comment: In addition: the procedure which consists from one statement does not need in delimiter reassign and BEGIN-END block.